# Evaluate $\int_0^1 x\sin^{-1}(x) \mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Evaluate $\int_0^1 x\sin^{-1}(x)\mathrm dx$

$$=[\sin^{-1}x \frac{x^2}{2}]_0^1 -\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\frac{x^2}{2}\mathrm dx$$
$$\sin^{-1}1\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\frac{x^2\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
$$\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\int_1^0\frac{\sqrt{z} z\mathrm dx}{z}$$

Taking, $1-x^2=z^2$ So, $-2x\mathrm dx=2z\mathrm dz$

$$\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{1}{2}[\frac{z^{\dfrac{3}{2}}}{\frac{3}{2}}]_1^0$$
$$\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{2}{3}$$

But, my book's answer was $\frac{\pi}{8}$. Where did I do wrong?

Comment: In the second integration substitute $x=\sin(\theta)$ instead. Then you will get $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^{2}(\theta) d\theta = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^{2}(\theta)d\theta$. Add the two integrals to get $2I=\frac{\pi}{2}\implies I=\frac{\pi}{4}$. The  you get the answer in the book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integration of $x^2/(1-x^2)^{1/2}$ is incorrect.  Presumably, you chose the substitution $z = \sqrt{1-x^2}$, or $x^2 = 1-z^2$.  Then $x \, dx = -z \, dz$, hence $$\int_{x=0}^1 \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \, dx = \int_{x=0}^1 \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} x \, dx = -\int_{z=1}^0 \frac{\sqrt{1-z^2}}{z} z \, dz.$$

Comment: Let $\arcsin x =\theta$ then $x=\sin \theta $. Hence the required integral is $\int_0^\frac {\pi}2 \theta \sin \theta \cos \theta d\theta$  
 
$ =\frac 12 \int_0^{\frac {\pi} 2}\theta \sin 2\theta d\theta $ 
$=\frac 18\int_0^ {\pi}z \sin z dz$(taking $2\theta=z$).
Can you conclude it from here?

Answer (score 0):

By integration by parts, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1 x \sin ^{-1} x d x & =\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \sin ^{-1} x d\left(x^2\right) \\
& = \underbrace{\frac{1}{2}\left[x^2 \sin ^{-1} x\right]_0^1}_{=\frac{\pi}{4}  } -\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} d x
\end{aligned}
$$
For the last integral, we let $x=\sin \theta$ and get
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} d x & =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin ^2 \theta}{\cos \theta} \cdot \cos \theta d \theta \\
& =\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(1+\cos 2 \theta) d \theta \\
& =\frac{1}{2}\left[\theta+\frac{\sin 2 \theta}{2}\right]_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \\
& =\frac{\pi}{4}
\end{aligned}
$$
Now we can conclude that
$$
\int_0^1 x \sin ^{-1} x d x  =\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{\pi}{4} =\frac{\pi}{8}
$$